# Finding the kernel of a linear operator involving direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, direct-sum

So the question I am working on is:

> Suppose $V = U_1\oplus U_2$. Define the linear operator $T$ on $V$ as follows: for every $v$ find $u_1\in U_1$ and $u_2\in U_2$ such that $v = u_1+u_2$, then $T(v)=u_1$.

Part (a) asks about the kernel of $T$. My professor taught me that the kernel of $T\colon V\to W$ (linear operator) is the set of vectors $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=0_W$.

When thinking of this question, I first thought about what the linear operator was doing to the input $v$. Because $v$ is the sum of $u_1$ and $u_2$, and the output is $u_1$, the linear operator was getting the sum of $u_1$ and $u_2$, and subtracting $u_2$ from it to get $u_1$. So I thought that the kernel of $T$ is
$$
\{ u_1 + u_2 = v ~|\, u_1 = 0 \}
$$

EDIT: 
$$
T(v) = u_1
$$
$$
T(u_1 + u_2) = T(u_1) + T (u_2) = u_1
$$
Would this mean that the $T(u_1)$ would be itself and the $T(u_2)$ would turn it to $0$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to [let you know a few things about the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour). On this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial. You can [edit] your own question by clicking the edit button below your question.

Comment: Instead of thinking of the linear operator as subtracting off $u_{2}$, I think it helps to recall the properties a linear operator satisfies and instead write $T(v) = T(u_{1}+u_{2}) = T(u_{1}) + T(u_{2}) = u_{1}$ to see that $T$ maps $u_{1}$ to itself and $u_{2}$ to $0_{W}$.

Comment: @JessicaK So would that make the kernel of $T$ to be all $v$'s where the $u_1$'s are $0$?

Comment: Yes, which is basically saying that the Kernel is $U_{2}$.

Comment: @JessicaK Would that make the range of T to be $U_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ask yourself: which are all the elements $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=0$? Clearly $Ker(V)=0\oplus U_2$, in fact let's take an element of this ensemble, $s=0+u_2$. By definition of the linear operator you have: $T(s)=T(0+u_2)=T(0)=0$

Comment: Do you mean $T(s) = T(0+u_2) = T(0) + T(u_2) = T(0) + 0 = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Since $u_1\in V$, $u_2\in V$ and $T$ a linear operator you can always write $T(u_1+u_2)=T(u_1)+T(u_2)$ and since you define $T$ s.t. $T(u_1+u_2)=T(u_1)$ it means that $T$ always map $U_2$ elements to 0.